# conditional showing of uitoolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that is presented in two ways, either modally or pushed on top of a navigation controller stack. The `UIViewController` contains a `UITableView` and a `UIToolbar`. When presented modally, i needed a way of showing a `title` for the `ViewController`, so I added in another `UIToolbar`, `topToolbar`. My problem is, whenever I push the `UIViewController`, I don't need `topToolbar` anymore, since the `navigation tabbar` already shows the title. When I set `topToolbar`'s hidden property to `true`, however, my `UITableView` is not bound to the bottom of the `navigation tab bar` and there's space between the `UITableView` and the `navigation tabbar`, which doesn't look so good. I tried to call `removeFromSuperview()` on `topToolbar` instead of setting its `hidden` property to `true`, but that didn't work out, and `topToolbar` appeared under the `navigation bar`, and now i have two `titles` instead of one. Any idea on how this can be done? I can't add pictures, but here's my code for manipulating the appearance of the `UIViewController` based on whether it's presented modally or pushed on top of the navigation stack:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if itemBought != nil {
        cart.items.append(itemBought!)
    }

    totalView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    totalView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    totalLabel.text = "$" + String(format: "%.2f", cart.getTotal())

    if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
        //hide toolbar and tabbar
        topToolbar.removeFromSuperview()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

        //hide shop button
        var bottomItems: [UIBarButtonItem] = bottomToolbar.items as! [UIBarButtonItem]
        if let index = find(bottomItems, shopToolbarButton) {
            bottomItems.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
        bottomToolbar.items = bottomItems
    }
}
```

I should also mention that i have a constraint on the `UITableView` that's basically: distance between `UItableView.top` and `Top Layout Guide.Bottom` is `<=` to the height of `topToolbar`, which is 44.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you present the View Controller modally, why not put it in a UINavigation Controller?

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewControllerInstance)

self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        //do something here when animation is complete if you want
    })
```